# Let's Play some ProSet!

Tags: code-golf, card-games, restricted-complexity

ProSet is a classic card game that is played normally with 63 cards. One card has 6 colored dots on it, like below

[image]

The rest of the cards are missing some of these 6 dots, but each card has at least 1 dot. Every card in the deck is different. Below are some example valid cards.

[image]

A **ProSet** is a **nonempty** set of cards such that the total number of each color of dot is even.  For example, the above set of 4 cards are a **ProSet** since there are 2 reds, 4 oranges, 2 greens, 2 blues, 0 yellows, and 2 purples.

Interestingly, any set of 7 cards will contain at least 1 **ProSet**. Hence, in the actual card game, a set of 7 cards are presented, and the player who finds a **ProSet** first wins. You can try the game out for yourself [here](http://www.mathcamp.org/2015/proset/).

## Challenge

Given a set of cards, each **ProSet** card can be assigned a value from 1 to 63 in the following manner: a red dot is worth 1 point, an orange 2 points, yellow 4, green 8, blue 16, purple 32. The sum of the values of each dot on the card is the value of the card.

**Input**: A list of integers from 1-63, i.e.,

```
[11,26,35,50]
```

This list represents the above 4 cards.

**Output**: The number of valid **ProSets**, which in this example is `1`.

## Rules

- This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge.
- This is also a [restricted-complexity](/questions/tagged/restricted-complexity) challenge, as all valid solutions **must** be in polynomial time or less in the number of dots (in this case 6) **and** in the number of cards.

## Test Cases

I've created an exponential algorithm to find the correct output for every input [here](https://tio.run/##bVLLboMwEDzDV/hSyTSAYqrkgOJ@QQ899GahiiZOs6kxlg1t6M/TNQ55SJWQvLsez8yOMEN3aHUxjtCY1nZE940ZSO2INvFO7n3/Aq6jeKYNaCU1Z0kZR0A4CX3G4khxUcXRzwGUJMXjI4UFSzYc3yAyggVHyL615EhAE1vrT0khzRh@nio6IRe@OnrspPjMT34eqbw2RuodZYlv8SbjJ6ykcvIesESAlV1vNVWiLDNWJZN9cK@2pWp2rE3@K23rKPpG4LJKkhtn6uwWUbW19UCPV1Y/U4rCQ8H5PyxJkHP9x7vCuBxthqnwwjh0qC1EVQUxuMbgGWbolIVGJKaHVUhTkw0nt6hpb6T0@YeRgFJX56mbA8E6ZEYWnLBgIreyab8lFdVlL@/YTda3B7n9kjZkpZD9uouYfwJI1wm5bKCuNFSEoOHuOt@2ve7om@0l5jMaC9jNOoKxtFinT6t05QMc/wA). Again, exponential solutions are **not** valid submissions. But, you can use this to validate your findings.

## Edit

I will address the comments in a bit.  But for now,  none of the answers have been in polynomial time. It is indeed possible,  so here's a hint: **binary** representation and two s complement.

Moreover, I made a mistake earlier when I said polynomial in solely dots. It needs to be polynomial in dots and cards.

Comment: Just another detail, the complexity is based in the number of dots, but what about the number of cards? can it be exponential to the number of cards?

Comment: I don't think complexity in the number of dots makes any sense since the number of dots is fixed in this problem? Wouldn't the naive solution (like Rod suggested) be exponential in the number of cards but linear in the number of dots?

Comment: Your reference implementation only checks contiguous sublists of the input.

Comment: More concrete test cases please, preferably considering any edge cases

Comment: To me, the complexity restriction spoils the challenge a little. Just code golf would have been more fun. Also, it may not be obvious if the restriction is being met by an answer or not; answer writers should explain

Comment: "A ProSet is a set of cards such that the total number of each color of dot is even" - the empty set is a set. As such the example output should be 2.

Comment: @JonathanAllen not including empty set

Comment: Out of the 6 existing answers, I don't think a single one is polynomial time. You may want to emphasize that requirement more.

Comment: [Exploring the xorspace](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/124703/20260) is closely related, possibly a duplicate. The number of prosets equals 2^(# elts) / (size of xorspace) - 1. I expect the polynomial-time restriction restriction to be effectively the same as finishing the xorspace test cases within a day.

Comment: @RushabhMehta No need to apologize, unexpected duplicates are common around here and I've had my share, especially with many different possibilities for terminology that can be used to phrase challenge.

Comment: @user2357112 "All current answers seem to be exponential in the number of input cards, which is worse, though" no, there is no given relationship between the number of dot-colours (the number of "dots" is said to be 6 in the example) and number of cards. All the "get the powerset of cards" solutions below, while exponential in the number of cards, are, strictly speaking, only linear in the dot-colour count (since keeping the number of cards fixed and varying the dot-colour count we can see a linear relationship).

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 60 bytes

```python
p=[0]
for i in input():p+=[n^i for n in p]
print~-p.count(0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v8A22iCWKy2/SCFTITMPiApKSzQ0rQq0baPz4jIVQBIgUYWCWK6Cosy8kjrdAr3k/NK8Eg0Dzf//ow0NdYzMdIxNdUwNYgE)
This generate the powerset from the input (based on [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51675/)), reducing each subset by `xor`.
The output will be the amount of `0`s (0 = all bytes/dots appear an even number of times).
<sup>In fact the xoring is done instead of the "powerset appending", but the result is the same</sup>

Comment: This is exponential in the number of dots.

Comment: @user2357112 no, it's not, it's exponential to the numbers of cards. I've asked some clarifcation to OP when I made this answer, since I don't got an answer, I posted anyway. But it is compliant to the question as it is now.

Comment: I was about to edit (actually, delete and repost) to say "cards".

Answer (score 1):

## Japt, 8 bytes

```
à x@!Xr^
```

[Try it here](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=4CB4QCFYcl4=&input=WzExLDI2LDM1LDUwXQ==)

Answer (score 0):

## Clojure, <strike>182</strike> <strike>166</strike> <strike>149</strike> 127 bytes

```
(defn f[k]((frequencies(map(fn[x](reduce #(bit-xor % %2)0 x))(reduce(fn[c n](concat(map #(concat %[n])c)[(list n)]c))'()k)))0))
```

If I had barfed on the screen, it would've looked better than this

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYtRCoMwEAWvslCk@8CCWuxlQj7suoFUu9oYwdtbpf0cZkbG6bUm3XfuNRgFN3jmkPSzqknUhd/dzMHc5jlpv4rShZ8x37YpUUFFg4o24O/OUMg8y2TS5fM98h9Q4cxD4HiMSyaDF@DKGABUwM5zipaJA7m6LptHeW/LtvKH@QI)

Comment: This only seems to check prefixes of the input.

Comment: Ah crap you're right. I'll update it when I have the time

Comment: Alright, that should do it.

Comment: This looks exponential time, but I don't know enough Clojure to confirm. The challenge requires a polynomial-time algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript (ES6), 53 bytes

```js
f=
a=>a.map(i=>p.map(j=>n+=p.push(j^=i)&&!j),p=[n=0])&&n
```

```html
<input oninput=o.textContent=f(this.value.split`,`)><pre id=o>
```

Loosely based on @Rod's Python answer.

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ŒPḊ^/€¬S
```

A monadic Link. 9 bytes if the empty set is considered a ProSet - `ŒPḊ^/€¬S‘` (since reducing an empty list errors).

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opICHO7ri9B81rTm0Jvj////RhoY6RmY6xqY6pgaxAA)**

#### How?

```
ŒPḊ^/€¬S - Link: list of integers, L
ŒP       - powerset (of cards)
  Ḋ      - dequeue (remove the empty list)
    /€   - reduce €ach with:
   ^     -   XOR
      ¬  - NOT (vectorises)
       S - sum
```

Answer (score -1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 88 bytes

```python
lambda l:~-sum(x<1for x in f(l))
f=lambda l:l and[n^l[0]for n in f(l[1:])]+f(l[1:])or[0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfbhvzPycxNyklUSHHqk63uDRXo8LGMC2/SKFCITNPIU0jR1OTK80WriRHITEvJTovLifaIBakKg@qKtrQKlYzVhvGyi8Cyv8vKMrMK1FI14g2NNQxMtMxNtUxNYjV/A8A)

Comment: @Downvoters could one of you explain what is wrong with this answer?